# Is it possible to run multiple web instance in the same AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

**Background**

I have followed this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-ec2.html, composed a docker compose file, made a website A (compose of 4 containers) up and run serving 1 of my client.

However, now I have another client which I need to host another web site website B using similar strategies as above.

Here is the current running service of ECS / EC2 
[image]

and here are the containers up and running, serving website A now
[image]

**Questions & concerns**

1. The website A is now situated as 1 of a service in the EC2 under my only cluster, can I use the same EC2 instance and run website B (as another service of the EC2)?
2. If so, how are the ports / inbound / outbound traffic being managed? Now website A already occupies port 80, 443, 27017 and 3002 of the EC2 instance for inbound traffic, if website B's containers also run in the same EC2 instances, can I still use port 80, 443, 27017 and 3002 for website B. I have read the docs of ALB (Amazon Load Balancer), seems it can fulfill the requirement, am I at the right track?
3. And the domain name, through route 53, I have registered a domain www.websiteA.com to serve the 1st website, I have also registered another www.websiteB.com preparing to serve website B, in my case, I guess I need to configure the new domain B pointing to the same EC2 IP?
4. During my deployment of website B, I do not want to affect the availability of website A, can it be maintained during the process of deploying website B's containers?

I want to clear all the concepts before kick-starting to deploy the website B, appreciate for any help, thank you

**Follow-up actions**

I come up decided to use AWS application load balancer to solve my issue, and have the following configurations setup.

I first look into load balancer
[image]

And configured as follows
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I setup a load balancer which listens for requests using HTTP protocol with incoming port 80, whenever there are users access the web server (i.e.: the frontend container), listener will forward that request to the target group (i.e.: http-port-80-access)

[image]
And here is the target group (http-port-80-access) which contains a registered target (currently my ec2 instance running the containers), the host port of the container is 32849 which in turn made used by the associated load balancer (web-access-load-balancer) for dynamic port mapping.

[image]
I have also configured 1 more rule on top of the default rule, whenever user access url of websiteA, load balancer will forward the request to the target group (http-port-80-access).

All things set, and the healthy test also passed. I then used the following `ecs-cli compose service up` command to wire up the load balancer with the service

```sh
ecs-cli compose --file ./docker-compose-aws-prod.yml --cluster my-ecs-cluster-name --ecs-profile my-ecs-profile --cluster-config my-cluster --project-name my-project --ecs-params ./ecs-params.yml service up --target-group-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxx:targetgroup/http-port-80-access/xxxxxxxx --container-name frontend --container-port 80
```

where frontend is the service name of the frontend container of website A

However, turn out when I access www.websiteA.com through browser, nothing but ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, accessing www.websiteA.com:32849 did accessible, but is not what I desired.

I am wondering which part I configured wrongly

Comment: How is traffic routing to your containers? Are you going directly to the IP of the EC2 instance? Are you using an ALB?

Comment: You could consider using [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: @JasonWadsworth yes, users are currently accessing website A through domain name website A (through direct IP of the EC2 instance). And I haven't use ALB yet, because I don't know ALB is the right thing to go

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I also found virtual hosts as 1 of the solution during my search, but how exactly should it be implemented in my case? AFAIK, I should build the server which has virtual host setup "ahead of" website A and website B, map the EC2 IP to that server for routing to different containers through virtual host configuration? In other words, I need to create another docker container (which maybe a nginx server) to receive the request, configure the virtual host and direct the EC2 IP to the nginx server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending traffic directly to the instance then you would have to host on a different port. You should consider using an ALB, which would allow you to use [dynamic ports in ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/). The ALB can accept traffic from ports 80 and 443 for different domains and route the traffic to different containers based on things like the domain.

Comment: Thanks! by hosting on different port, that means my docker-compose port mapping should not map to port 80/443 again for website B? Or I can still use it in port mapping of the compose file and use ALB to handle the traffic route? (As I want both sites can be accessible through 80/443)

Comment: Inside the container it can use any port you want. That is the "container port" inside a task definition.

Comment: Thanks Jason. If I understand correctly, the container port internally communicating can keep intact, but the mapping port of host cannot be 80? Say my website A already configures 80:80 for the "ports mapping", for website B, the port mapping (of the host part) cannot use port 80, should e.g. use 81:80?

Comment: When you are using dynamic port mapping you don't specify the host port, only the internal port.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I just started to read the ALB docs, in that case, I need to remove the host port specification of both compose file of website A and B before starting to apply ALB? Or can I just keep the current setting of website A? If so, I need to restart website A for the changes, thanks

Comment: I believe you need to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, seems like ALB is a right track, I started creating a load balancer now but seems only 80 & 443 ports are allowed for load balancer?? How about other ports, can I also do the load balancer? say port 27017 for external database access?

Comment: For none http traffic you’ll need to use an NLB.

Answer (score 1):

> The website A is now situated as 1 of a service in the EC2 under my only cluster, can I use the same EC2 instance and run website B (as another service of the EC2)?

Indeed. However - as you already found out, you have to split the traffic based on something (hostname, path,..). That's where the reverse-proxy comes in play (either managed - ALB, NLB or your own - nginx, haproxy,.. ) .

It's simple for the http traffic (based on the host)

> If so, how are the ports / inbound / outbound traffic being managed? Now website A already occupies port 80, 443, 27017 and 3002 of the EC2 instance for inbound traffic, if website B's containers also run in the same EC2 instances, can I still use port 80, 443, 27017 and 3002 for website B.

assuming the ports 27017 and the 3002 are using own binary protocol (not http). You will have handle that.

You can in theory define the port mapping (map different public listening port to these custom ports), but then you need to either use NLB (network load balancer) or expose the ports on hosts public IP. In the latter case I'm not sure with ECS you can guarantee which IP is used (e.g. having multiple worker nodes)

> I have read the docs of ALB (Amazon Load Balancer), seems it can fulfill the requirement, am I at the right track?

ALB is layer 7 reverse proxy (http), it is imho the best option for the  web access, not for binary protocols.

> , I guess I need to configure the new domain B pointing to the same EC2 IP?

that's the plan

> During my deployment of website B, I do not want to affect the availability of website A, can it be maintained during the process of deploying website B's containers?

shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thanks gusto, I am clearer on what I should do next. But in my case, since I need both web protocol and binary protocols dynamic port binding, I guess I need both application load balancer and network load balancer? As the doc states that network load balancer sits on layer 4 (TCP/IP), I think it fits my needs on entertaining external traffic of 27017 and 3002?

Comment: @user2361494 Yes, that's the idea. However - each load balancer costs something. I'd try to create single NLB to a hosted (extra pod) reverse proxy, such as nginx or haproxy, which you could use to serve the web part.

Comment: Thanks, I dug into the configuration of ALB several hours but can't seem to make the desired deployment work, I have updated the follow up actions on the original thread to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

Run website B on different ports.  To allow end users to interact with website B without specify port numbers use a reverse-proxy.  See AWS CloudFront.